# How to check from output of a cmdlet if it contains a specific string and return success in Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, smb

I am checking if SMB version 1 is enabled or not on my Windows Server 2008 R2.

Even though SMB1 is enabled and running, when I am doing a **if loop comparison** if SMB1 is running then it is executing the **else condition**

Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Here is my script :

```
$SMBVersionRunning = sc.exe query mrxsmb10
$SMBVersionState = $SMBVersionRunning | Select-String -Pattern "STATE"
$SMBRunningStatus = $SMBVersionState | Select-String -Pattern "RUNNING"

if( $SMBVersionRunning.Contains($SMBRunningStatus.ToString()) -eq 0)
{
    Write-Host "SMB1 is enabled"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "SMB1 is not enabled"
}
```

Comment: shot in the dark, but have you looked at `Get-SmbServerConfiguration | Select EnableSMB1Protocol, EnableSMB2Protocol`

Comment: Get-SmbServerConfiguration cmdlet is not supported in Windows 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Get-Service` allows a simpler and more robust solution:

```
if ((Get-Service mrxsmb10).Status -eq 'Running') {
    "SMB1 is enabled"
}
else {
    "SMB1 is not enabled"
}
```

<sup>If there's a chance that the service isn't even *installed*, add `-ErrorAction Ignore` (PSv5+) or `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to the `Get-Service` call in order to silence error output.</sup>

---

If you do want to stick with the string-parsing approach, you can simplify your attempt to the following:

```
if ((sc.exe query mrxsmb10) -match 'STATE' -match 'RUNNING') {
    "SMB1 is enabled"
}
else {
    "SMB1 is not enabled"
}
```

<sup>While probably not necessary in this case, you could make the matching stricter by looking for the search terms only as *full words*, by enclosing them with `\b...\b`; i.e., `\bSTATE\b` and `\bRUNNING\b`</sup>

---

As for what you tried:

`if ($SMBRunningStatus) ...` should give you what you want, because it will only be nonempty if both the string `STATE` and `RUNNING` were found on the same line, and a nonempty variable is "truthy" in a conditional (in any Boolean context).

`$SMBVersionRunning.Contains($SMBRunningStatus.ToString())` doesn't work as intended, because it is not a *string* operation, but an *array containment* operation, given that invocation of an external program such as `sc.exe query mrxsmb10` returns an *array* of lines.

That is, the method call would only return `$True` if `$SMBRunningStatus.ToString()` matched a line *in full*.

Aside from that, your logic of comparing to `-eq 0` (a) compares the Boolean result from `.Contains()` to an `[int]` and (b) has the logic accidentally reversed; to test if a Boolean result is `$True`, you *can* use `-eq $True`, but that isn't necessary: simply use the Boolean result as-is; similarly, to test for `$False` you can use the `-not` operator instead of `-eq $False`.